# Получить значение по id из span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть AJAX запрос. Возвращает вот такую строчку.

```
<li>Медучереждения 3<span id="id_hf" style="display:none;">20</span></li>
```

Есть обработчик, когда я нажимаю на выбранные li

```
$('#autosuggest li').on('click', function() {
    var string = $(this).text();

    $('#hf').val(string);
    $hfResult.fadeOut('fast'); 
});
```

Как мне получить значение тега `<span>` внутри тега `<li>`.

У меня будут два `<input>`.

В первый будет записываться при клике все что до `<span>`
Во второй будет записывать все что в `<span>`

Comment: у вас вопрос обрывается, но непонятно зачем эти подробности, ну конечно если суть выше изложена верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так:

```
$(this).find('span').text()
```

Comment: Класс спасибо! А как получить текст до span?

Comment: `$(this).contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == 3; 
})[0].nodeValue`

но лучше используйте атрибуты `data-`

Comment: т.е. если уже никак нельзя возвращать с сервера JSON, возвращайте:
`<li data-medcount="20">Медучереждения 3</li>`

Comment: Спасибо действительно через атрибуты проще!